# Definition of $\limsup_{|t|\rightarrow\infty}$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Please I have this two conditions: $$\limsup_{|t|\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(t)}{|t|^s}=0~~\text{and}~~ \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{f(t)}{|t|^{p-1}}=0$$ where $2\leq p<N$ $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ function and $s\in (0,\frac{N(p-1)+p}{N-p})$ and the function $\frac{f(t)}{t^{p-1}}$ is increasing in $(0,+\infty)$

How to deduce that: $$\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists C_{\varepsilon}>0~~\text{such that}~~|f(t)|\leq\varepsilon|t|+C_{\varepsilon} t^s, \forall t\in (0,+\infty)$$

Thank you.

Comment: Is $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{f(t)}{|t|^{p-1}}=0$?

Comment: @robjohn yes sorry i don't see

Comment: @robjohn have you an idea please

Comment: Assume only that $$\limsup_{|t|\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{|t|^a}<\infty\qquad\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(t)}{|t|^b}=0$$ with $a$ and $b$ positive, and that $f$ is continuous. There exists some finite $A$ such that, for every $|t|$ large enough, say, every $|t|>C$, $|f(t)|<A|t|^a$. For every $|t|$ small enough, say, every $|t|<c$, $|f(t)|<\varepsilon |t|^b$. Add to this that $|f(t)|$ is bounded on $c\leqslant |t|\leqslant C$, say, $|f(t)|\leqslant K$, to deduce that, for every $t$, $$|f(t)|\leqslant \varepsilon |t|^b+\max(A,K/c^a)|t|^a.$$

Comment: @Did what is the difinition for $\limsup_{|t|\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{|t|^a}=0$ please , $\exists A$ or $\forall A$ ?? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou Sorry but I fail to see how your query is related to my comment. If it is not, please find the definition yourself, either on the internet or in your notes.